# Name of the dataframe from which the minimum value is taken

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 3 data-frames as below.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( {"val" : [1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111, 11111],
                    "val2" : [2, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],"val3" : [33333, 33333, 3333, 333, 33, 3]} )
val     val2    val3
1          2    33333
11        22    33333
111       23    3333
1111      24    333
11111     25    33
11111     26    3
```

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame( {"val" : [2, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26],"val2" : [1, 11, 111, 1111, 11111, 11111],"val3" : [3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3] } )
val     val2    val3
2         1     3
22       11     3
23      111     3
24     1111     3
25    11111     3
26    11111     3
```

&

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame( {"val" : [33333, 33333, 3333, 333, 33, 3],"val2" : [3, 3, 3, 3333, 3, 3],"val3" : [2, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26] } )
val     val2    val3
33333      3    2
33333      3    22
3333       3    23
333     3333    24
33         3    25
3          3    26
```

With the code `pd.concat([df1,df2,df3]).min(level=0)` , I get a dateframe which has the min value of each cell of these 3 dataframes

```
val     val2    val3
1         1     2
11        3     3
23        3     3
24       24     3
25        3     3
3         3     3
```

Now, my question is there a way to get a dataframe which shows from which dataframe these individual values have come from? The expected out put is as below

```
val     val2    val3
df1     df2     df3
df1     df3     df2
df2     df3     df2
df2     df1     df2
df2     df3     df2
df3     df3     df1,df2
```

Is this even possible in Pandas?

Comment: df1-df3 are python variables, what you want as it is not possible unless you dig deep into python, like using introspection module. it's not something pandas has any control over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `numpy.ma.apple_along_axis`:

```
def min_finder(arr1d,sep=","):
    return ",".join(["df%s" % i for i in np.argwhere(arr1d == arr1d.min()).ravel()+1])

new_df = pd.DataFrame(np.ma.apply_along_axis(min_finder, 2, np.stack(dfs, 0)).T)
print(new_df)

     0    1        2
0  df1  df2      df3
1  df1  df3      df2
2  df2  df3      df2
3  df2  df3      df3
4  df2  df3      df2
5  df3  df3  df1,df2
```

If you don't want tie, use `numpy.argmin`:

```
dfs = [df1,df2,df3]
np.stack(dfs, 0).argmin(0)
```

Output:

```
array([[0, 1, 2],
       [0, 2, 1],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [1, 0, 1],
       [1, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 0]])
```

Or make it bit prettier:

```
np.char.add("df", (np.stack(dfs, 0).argmin(0)+1).astype(str))

array([['df1', 'df2', 'df3'],
       ['df1', 'df3', 'df2'],
       ['df2', 'df3', 'df2'],
       ['df2', 'df1', 'df2'],
       ['df2', 'df3', 'df2'],
       ['df3', 'df3', 'df1']], dtype='<U23')
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. Your answer suits my purpose the best.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using a dictionary and `df.isin` followed by a pivot table, may be a little lengthy as I might have swayed a little while testing , but does the job

```
dict_of_dfs = {'df1':df1,'df2':df2,'df3':df3}
concated = pd.concat(dict_of_dfs.values())
a = np.vstack([np.where(v.isin(concated.min(level=0)),k,np.nan) 
              for k,v in dict_of_dfs.items()])
b = pd.DataFrame(a,columns=concated.columns,index=concated.index).replace('nan',np.nan)
print(b.head(10))

    val val2 val3
0  df1  NaN  NaN
1  df1  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  df1  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN  df1
0  NaN  df2  NaN
1  NaN  NaN  df2
2  df2  NaN  df2
3  df2  NaN  df2
```

Then using `pivot_table` (*of course you can make custom changes to drop extra levels and renaming index*)

```
final = b.stack().reset_index()
final.pivot_table(index='level_0',columns='level_1',values=0,aggfunc=','.join)
```

---

```
level_1  val val2     val3
level_0                   
0        df1  df2      df3
1        df1  df3      df2
2        df2  df3      df2
3        df2  df1      df2
4        df2  df3      df2
5        df3  df3  df1,df2
```

Comment: Thanks Anky for your answer. Chris's answer suits me best hence I am accepting it (I have up-voted yours).

Answer (score 2):

This is a *basic* approach that maps values to the name of their data frames, finds mins, then discards values:

```
(pd.concat([df1.applymap(lambda a: (a, 'df1')),
            df2.applymap(lambda a: (a, 'df2')),
            df3.applymap(lambda a: (a, 'df3'))])
   .min(level=0)
   .applymap(lambda a: a[1]))

   val val2 val3
0  df1  df2  df3
1  df1  df3  df2
2  df2  df3  df2
3  df2  df1  df2
4  df2  df3  df2
5  df3  df3  df1
```

Note that the first data frame by name will be returned where values are equal.

Comment: Thanks Ernest for your answer. Chris's answer suits me best hence I am accepting it (I have up-voted yours).